# typeAnnotation error on spread

Tags: flowtype

My code is the following:

```
import type { Shape as BrowserActionShape } from '../../../flow-control/browser-action'

type Props = {
    // redux
    ...BrowserActionShape
}

const rawr:Props= { title:'blah' } // this works
```

Definition of BrowserShape is here:

```
export type Shape = {
    badgeColor?: string,
    badgeText?: string,
    title?: string
}
```

Flow is working perfectly fine, however building with webpack is causing this compile error and failure:

```
ERROR in ./src/webext/background/Background/BrowserAction/index.js
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'typeAnnotation' of undefined
    at Referencer.checkIdentifierOrVisit (C:\Users\Blagoh\Documents\GitHub\My-Cool-App\node_modules\babel-eslint\index.js:206:13)
    at Referencer.visitTypeAnnotation (C:\Users\Blagoh\Documents\GitHub\My-Cool-App\node_modules\babel-eslint\index.js:181:38)
    at Referencer.referencer.TypeAlias (C:\Users\Blagoh\Documents\GitHub\My-Cool-App\node_modules\babel-eslint\index.js:347:27)
    at Referencer.Visitor.visit (C:\Users\Blagoh\Documents\GitHub\My-Cool-App\node_modules\esrecurse\esrecurse.js:122:34)
    at Referencer.Visitor.visitChildren (C:\Users\Blagoh\Documents\GitHub\My-Cool-App\node_modules\esrecurse\esrecurse.js:101:38)
    at Referencer.Program (C:\Users\Blagoh\Documents\GitHub\My-Cool-App\node_modules\escope\lib\referencer.js:419:18)
    at Referencer.Visitor.visit (C:\Users\Blagoh\Documents\GitHub\My-Cool-App\node_modules\esrecurse\esrecurse.js:122:34)
    at Object.analyze (C:\Users\Blagoh\Documents\GitHub\My-Cool-App\node_modules\escope\lib\index.js:153:16)
    at Object.escope.analyze (C:\Users\Blagoh\Documents\GitHub\My-Cool-App\node_modules\babel-eslint\index.js:90:27)
    at EventEmitter.module.exports.api.verify (C:\Users\Blagoh\Documents\GitHub\My-Cool-App\node_modules\eslint\lib\eslint.js:892:35)
    at processText (C:\Users\Blagoh\Documents\GitHub\My-Cool-App\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine.js:264:31)
    at CLIEngine.executeOnText (C:\Users\Blagoh\Documents\GitHub\My-Cool-App\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine.js:754:26)
    at lint (C:\Users\Blagoh\Documents\GitHub\My-Cool-App\node_modules\eslint-loader\index.js:218:17)
    at Object.module.exports (C:\Users\Blagoh\Documents\GitHub\My-Cool-App\node_modules\eslint-loader\index.js:213:21)
 @ ./src/webext/background/Background/index.js 35:21-47
```

I am not able to fix this. I am using flow-bin 0.53.1 - I don't recall this error in previous version of flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, hard to say. Similar code seems to work for me. Can you check that you have a recent version of `babel`, the Babel Flow preset, and `babel-eslint`? And if upgrading them doesn't fix, can you provide the versions you currently use and details about your babel/webpack configuration?

Comment: Thank you sir for trying to help with such a confusing error. I will try that and let you know :)

Comment: I run update, and the red ones in this screenshot got updated - http://i.imgur.com/2dy8KwF.png - however still same error. I am going to try to upgrade to the "latest in purple" now and try again.

Comment: I didn't have a babel flow preset so I installed `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types` then added to my `plugins` on `.babelrc` - `plugins": ["transform-flow-strip-types"]` this didn't fix it either. Will try to update to the "latest in purple" now.

Comment: Oh wow!! I don't know which was responsible but I updated `babel-eslint` from ^6 to ^7, `babel-loader` from ^6 to ^7, `eslint` from ^3 to ^4, `eslint-plugin-react` from ^6 to ^7 and it worked. I didn't even need `transform-flow-strip-types`, do you think I should keep `transform-flow-strip-types`? I thought flow types were stripped already on build, is this not true?